# Is there any fmod function in actionscript 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3

I searched the official actionscript reference for the Math class (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html) but it doesn't say anything about an fmod function 
Is there a way to use fmod in actionscript?

Comment: Have you considered using the `% Operator`? [Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#modulo)

Comment: It's not really the same.

Comment: Could you explain how it's not the same?  `trace("fmod: " + (5.3 % 2.0));` prints 1.3, matching the example in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmod/

Comment: @Brian Probably "not the same" means 11.1%3 vs fmod(11.1, 3). 
fmod returns 2.1, % operator returns 2.0999999999999996.

Comment: @YasuyukiUno Those two are the same, within floating-point error bounds.

Answer (score 1):

How about use this [BigDecimal class for AS3](https://code.google.com/archive/p/bigdecimal/source/default/source).

```
var x : BigDecimal = new BigDecimal(11.1);
var bdval : BigDecimal = x.remainder(new BigDecimal(3));
trace(bdval.numberValue());     // 2.1 = fmod(11.1, 3);
```

and create your own fmod function.

```
function fmod(a:Number, b:Number): Number
{
    var x : BigDecimal = new BigDecimal(a);
    var bdval : BigDecimal = x.remainder(new BigDecimal(b));

    return bdval.numberValue();
}

trace(fmod(4.3, 2.1)); // 0.1
```